# changing input on click to option tag

Tags: javascript

I'm having the following code

```
<li>
   <input type="checkbox" name="adfil_variants[Size][]" value="25" onclick="javascript: func_adfil_select_checkbox_filter(this);" id="adfil_variants_Size_25" />
   <label for="adfil_variants_Size_25"> 25</label>
</li>
```

And I'm trying to change it to something like this only the onclick is not supported by the option tag.

```
<select>

<option  type="checkbox" name="adfil_variants[Size][]" value="n31" onclick="javascript: func_adfil_select_checkbox_filter(this);" id="adfil_variants_Size_n31" /><label for="adfil_variants_Size_n31"> n31</option>

<option type="checkbox" name="adfil_variants[Size][]" value="24" onclick="javascript: func_adfil_select_checkbox_filter(this);" id="adfil_variants_Size_24" /><label for="adfil_variants_Size_24"> 24</option>

 </select>
```

the external javascript file:

```
function func_adfil_select_checkbox_filter(item) {

  document.advancedfilterform.submit();
}

function func_adfil_select_slider_filter() {

  $('#selector_changed').val('Y');

  document.advancedfilterform.submit();
}

function func_adfil_select_color_filter(gid, id) {

  if ($('[id="color_selector_' + gid + '_' + id + '"]').val() == '') {
    $('[id="color_selector_' + gid + '_' + id + '"]').val(id);
  } else {
    $('[id="color_selector_' + gid + '_' + id + '"]').val('');
  }

  document.advancedfilterform.submit();
}

function func_adfil_process_expandable_menu(id) {

  if ($('#' + id + '_content').css('display') == 'none') {
    $('#' + id + '_content').css('display', 'block');
    $('#' + id + '_collaps').css('display', 'block');
    $('#' + id + '_expand').css('display', 'none');
  } else {
    $('#' + id + '_content').css('display', 'none');
    $('#' + id + '_collaps').css('display', 'none');
    $('#' + id + '_expand').css('display', 'block');
  }
}
```

Comment: where is `func_adfil_select_checkbox_filter`?

Comment: Can you use jQuery, or at the very least, not use inline js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<select onchange="javascript: func_adfil_select_checkbox_filter(this);">
    <option  type="checkbox" name="adfil_variants[Size][]" value="n31" id="adfil_variants_Size_n31" />
        <label for="adfil_variants_Size_n31"> n31
    </option>
    <option type="checkbox" name="adfil_variants[Size][]" value="24" id="adfil_variants_Size_24" />
    <label for="adfil_variants_Size_24"> 24</option>
</select>
```

The [`onChange`](http://www.w3.org/WAI/UA/TS/html401/cp0102/0102-ONCHANGE-SELECT.html) attribute is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Add `onChange` to your "select" rather than `onclick` to each "option".

Also, if inclined to use jQuery, you could give the options a class name say "selectClass", or id of "selectId" then use jQuery to bind the click event to any element with the class "selectClass", or "selectId" as such:

```
$('.selectClass').change(function(){
    func_adfil_select_checkbox_filter($(this).val());
});
```

OR

```
$('#selectId').change(function(){
    func_adfil_select_checkbox_filter($(this).val());
});
```